# Python Pandas - Timeseries - Timestamp missing time exact at 00:00

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I am trying to read in a csv with a time series of measured values. I have the problem that the time stamp omits the time at 00:00 at the extraction from the measurement system.

Here is an excerpt from a csv file:

```
Time    NS          Status  u12 u23 u31 p1  q1
27.12.2023 23:30:00 0   0   20854,6 20482,8 20706,1 7599130 -2050710
27.12.2023 23:40:00 0   0   20882,8 20510,9 20728,6 7494070 -2078320
27.12.2023 23:50:00 0   0   20819,2 20448,5 20674,7 7672400 -1929610
28.12.2023          0   0   20792,9 20413,2 20645,9 7565910 -1942710
28.12.2023 00:10:00 0   0   20768,6 20368,6 20613,4 7174330 -2002890
```

And I used:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Python/Input/measured_values.csv',
                 sep = '\t', decimal=',',
                 skiprows=1, encoding='unicode_escape',
                 parse_dates=['Time'], dayfirst=True)
```

- I have tried different parameters from the parse_dates function to solve the problem
- I also tried to create a new timestamp with incrementing the time between the start and end of the time series - with isn't simple because i have to pay attention to the time change

is there a simple and efficient, robust solution to read in this sort of csv and declare the column time as datetime64[ns] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to pass `date_format='mixed'`, and should probably remove `skiprows=1`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', decimal=',', encoding='unicode_escape',
                 parse_dates=['Time'], dayfirst=True, date_format='mixed')

print(df)
                 Time  NS          Status      u12      u23      u31       p1       q1
0 2023-12-27 23:30:00   0               0  20854.6  20482.8  20706.1  7599130 -2050710
1 2023-12-27 23:40:00   0               0  20882.8  20510.9  20728.6  7494070 -2078320
2 2023-12-27 23:50:00   0               0  20819.2  20448.5  20674.7  7672400 -1929610
3 2023-12-28 00:00:00   0               0  20792.9  20413.2  20645.9  7565910 -1942710
4 2023-12-28 00:10:00   0               0  20768.6  20368.6  20613.4  7174330 -2002890

print(df.dtypes)
Time              datetime64[ns]
NS                         int64
        Status             int64
u12                      float64
u23                      float64
u31                      float64
p1                         int64
q1                         int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like your issue is with the CSV file not including the time component when it's exactly midnight.

To handle this, you can preprocess the CSV file to ensure that the time component is included for all timestamps before reading it into a DataFrame.

Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read the CSV file as text

```
with open('C:/Python/Input/measured_values.csv', 'r', 
encoding='unicode_escape') as file:
lines = file.readlines()
```

Preprocess lines to ensure time component is included for all timestamps

```
processed_lines = []
for line in lines:
    parts = line.split()
    if len(parts) >= 3 and ':' not in parts[2]:
        # If time component is missing, add it
        parts.insert(2, '00:00:00')
    processed_lines.append(' '.join(parts))
```

Write the preprocessed lines back to a temporary file

```
with open('temp.csv', 'w', encoding='unicode_escape') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(processed_lines))
```

Read the preprocessed CSV file into a DataFrame

```
df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', sep='\t', decimal=',', skiprows=1, 
parse_dates=['Time'], dayfirst=True)
```

Optionally, you can remove the temporary file

```
import os
os.remove('temp.csv')
```

Now df should have the timestamps with the correct time component included

```
print(df.head())
```

After that, read it into a DataFrame using pd.read_csv(). This should solve your issue of missing time components at midnight.

Comment: [Please don't post AI generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)

Comment: @mozway how did you spot this was AI generated? asking for my own education :)

Comment: @Tasos there are many hints, however I can't discuss those openly to avoid giving AI-spammer tools on how to avoid detection. If you're interested in fighting against AI content there are SO user groups to do that.